# Javascript inside HTML does not work to display a specific div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code inside my HTML. Here's the code:

```
<body>
<div id="div_inner_title">
    <img class="img_title" src="../common/img/header_logo.png"></img>
    <a id="menuId"><img class="img_menu" src="img/btn_menu.png"></img></a>                     
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#menuId").click(function (){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#div_menu_links").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        });
});</script>
</div>
.
.
.
.
.<!--Somewhere really below is a menu-->
.
.
<div class="div_menu_links">
    <a href="....">
        <img src="../common/img/menu_01.png" class="img_menu_button"></img>
    </a>
    <img class="img_menu_line_button" src="../common/img/menu_line.gif"></img>
<a href="....">
        <img src="../common/img/menu_02.png" class="img_menu_button"></img>
    </a> 
<img class="img_menu_line_button" src="../common/img/menu_line.gif" ></img>
<a href="....">
        <img src="../common/img/menu_03.png" class="img_menu_button"></img>
    </a> 
<img class="img_menu_line_button" src="../common/img/menu_line.gif"></img>
 <a href="....">
        <img src="../common/img/menu_04.png"class="img_menu_button"></img>
    </a>        
</div>
</body>
```

What I really wanted to do is when the user clicks the image button with javascript, the div menu is displayed on the screen (since it is located way down in the actual website).
However, the above code does not work. Just for additional info, the "transfer" from the image button to the div menu has an animated effect.

To be honest, I am not super genius programmer so please do help me. This is the only thing left not working on my page. Thanks!

Comment: What browser do you use? Can you, in JS console call this code `console.log($("#div_menu_links").offset())` and tell me what is the output?

Comment: Also can you check JS console for any errors?

Comment: Have you added the `jQuery` library?

Comment: Add this right before the `</body>`: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and test it again.

Comment: @m.spyratos jQuery isn't useful if you include it **after** you use it.

Comment: You have `div_menu_links` as a `class` attribute, but you're trying to select it as an `id`. [Otherwise, your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/TKSKf/).

Comment: @m.spyratos yes i've included the library. sorry it is not shown but it is declared on the header.

Comment: @Carlos i tested in both chrome and firefox, and even on mobile safari. does not work in all three.

Comment: @Rikonator originally that was an "id" but tried changing it to class thinking it might work. but still didn't. but will try again now.

Comment: @Ian You are right... I was thinking of having the code right below the call.

Comment: @user2273292 Check the demo code I have provided below. Try to achieve the same. Make sure you wrap your elements correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this simple example and try to achieve the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxGRN/2/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="menuId">Go Down</a>

<div id="div_menu_links">
    Reached the bottom menu! :)
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
// Just for demonstration
#div_menu_links { margin-top:2000px;}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#menuId").on("click", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#div_menu_links").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**A NOTE**

Do not rely on others to detect your errors. Start learning how to use `firebug`, with this simple tutorial: [Firebug Tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php)

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly how I want it to look like. I've edited the id parts from class and still it won't work with my codes.

Comment: Did you replace the javascript part too? Do you have any other javascript code inside the page?

Comment: Yes I've tried editing the JS too. Still, the code does not work. And yes, I have other JS codes inside the page. This is the only one located inside the body, the rest are on the header.

Comment: This is the site -- http://www.hikari-kindergarten.com/sphone/contents_events/index.html

Comment: By the way, it's best viewed on smartphone :)

Comment: You are trying to load `swipe.js` from here: `http://www.hikari-kindergarten.com/sphone/contents_events/javascript/swipe.js`, but it does not exist. That causes en error.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I already did an edit but still the JS does not work.

Comment: If you are not going to use the `swiper.js`, then remove `javascript/functions.js`, which is what actually causes the error.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That worked. Thank you. Sorry for being so programming dumb

Comment: No, you are not being programming dumb. Please check my note. Glad I could help!